# How do I shorthand boolean language for writing conditions?

Tags: javascript, boolean, conditional-statements, var

I have a list of variables that I call tags. Each one changes value from true to false depending on the function executed. These 'tags' act as builder pieces for booleans that I'd like to add in other variables. Basically, I'm trying to shorthand the language in order to make complex boolean conditions. Is this code correct for Javascript? The conditions are not passing as I've intended. `cleared` would read as `true` while  `runScreen` and `runIndicator` read as `true`

*Update* **I shortened the code and made a function to help strengthen the emphasis on the issue. Please see the code below.**

Thanks

```
//builder variables for condition
    let testValueA;
    let testValueB;

//condition shorthanded inside a variable
const testCondition = !testValueA && testValueB;


// test function for condition
function testCondionValue() {
  testValueA=Math.random() > 0.5;
  testValueB=Math.random() > 0.5;
  console.log("testValueA is", testValueA, "and testValueB is", testValueB);

  if (testCondition) {
    console.log(" therefore testCondition is true")
  }
  else {
    console.log("therefore testCondition is false")
  }
}
```

Comment: for booleans you could initialize with a boolean value. btw, you need not to wrap the complete expression with parentheses.

Comment: Thank you, Nina

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var cleared = (noHover && !runScreen && !runIndicator);

runScreen is true, then !runScreen is false, then cleared is false.
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: @navylover 
Yes, I understand your logic here. But my Chrome browser doesn't seem to agree. I continuously receive `cleared` as `true` within the console regardless if `runScreen` or `runIndicator` are `false` or `true`. This is the issue that I have. I must be writing the code incorrectly for the logic I need implemented.

Thanks